# react native flatlist usememo not working

Tags: react-native, expo

I hward I should avoid rerendering. So why is this code not working ?

RenderItem is not a function.

```
import React, { memo, useMemo } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, Image, Dimensions } from 'react-native';

const Shopping_cart = ({ datas, onPressSetting }) => {
  const RenderItem = useMemo((item) => {
    return (
      <Text>Hello</Text>
    )
  }, [datas]);
  return (
    <FlatList 
      data={datas}
      keyExtractor={item => item.item.product_id}
      renderItem={({ item }) => RenderItem(item)}
    />
  )
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try to pass **RenderItem** as a component.

**Example**

```
import React, { memo, useMemo } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, Image, Dimensions } from 'react-native';

const Shopping_cart = ({ datas, onPressSetting }) => {
  const RenderItem = useMemo(({item}) => {
    return (
      <Text>{item.title}</Text>
    )
  }, [datas]);
  return (
    <FlatList 
      data={datas}
      keyExtractor={item => item.item.product_id}
      renderItem={({ item }) => <RenderItem item={item} />}
    />
  )
};
```

Comment: And how can I use it without arrow function ? beacuse of the performance